# Is there a problem in the codes as data are not inserted in sql in php

Tags: php, sql

I am not using localhost and I tried my best, as a newer to PHP, to insert data to SQL but I was unsuccessful.

The codes are as follows:

```html
<?php
$host= "AAAA";
$user= "AAAA";
$pass= "AAAA";
$db= "AAAA";

$x1 = $_POST['X1'];
$x2 = $_POST['X2'];
$y1 = $_POST['Y1'];
$y2 = $_POST['Y2'];

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (X1, X2, Y1, Y2) values ('$x1', '$x2', '$y1', '$y2')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // execute the query
?>
```

I want to insert data into SQL, but not sure why I do not get into it. 
I do not get any error in the form, but When I check SQL, I cant see the data that I have entred.

Comment: Check the success of `mysqli_query`. Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection, you should use a prepared statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Try adding some error reporting. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php or even the connection could have failed, https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments for error checking.

Comment: I have updated, mysqli_query give me the same outcome, i.e., data are not appeared in sql

Comment: I have used  this before $Con= mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); but I did not get error